# "Animating" circle overlay with circle renderer on map view flickers

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I need to change radius of my `MKCircle` continuously as user pinches on the screen. As its `radius` property is read-only, I am removing and recreating the circle and the renderer continuously, which, I believe, causes "flickering" effect when user pinches. It continuously appears/disappears when "animating" which looks really bad visually, creating a crappy UX. Here is my code:

```
//this method may be called many times a second.
-(void)refreshRadius{ //called when user pinches after updating to correct radius.
    if(radiusCircle){
        [self.mapView removeOverlay:radiusCircle];
    }
    radiusCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:userCoordinates radius:radius];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:radiusCircle level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
}

-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{
    if(overlay == radiusCircle){
        MKCircleRenderer *renderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:radiusCircle];
        renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5];
        renderer.lineWidth = 0.8;
        renderer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.36 blue:0.7 alpha:0.2];
        return renderer;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

How can I "animate" the radius smoothly on scale?

Comment: @Rob Oh, I imagine how it works, but my circles are not opaque, for an instant they should be overlapping (as, from what we've seen, insertions and removings are not atomic in this case) and it would look bad. However, I've found a working solution (or workaround), see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit experimenting, I've luckily found a solution. However, while it works perfectly now, it's prone to future internal changes in iOS SDK. I've first set the read-only property "radius" using KVC. Then, I've invalidated my renderer's path, causing it to redraw itself immediately using the new radius. It is not the most-smooth-60FPS-animation-ever but it works really nicely. Here is the code:

```
[radiusCircle setValue:@(radius) forKey:@"radius"];
[renderer invalidatePath];
```

`radiusCircle` is my `MKCircle` instance, and `renderer` is my circle renderer. It works.